# How to parallelize this query in Python (just like PLINQ)?

Tags: c#, python, multithreading, python-multithreading, plinq

I'm having some issues with a query I wrote in Python (have to use it for TensorFlow), which works just fine but is way too slow, since the input dataset is quite big. It can take over 5 minutes for the query to complete, and checking the Task Manager I can confirm it's indeed running on a single core.

Here's the code:

```
# Assume words is a list of strings
for i, pair in enumerate(sorted(
    ((word, words.count(word))          # Map each word to itself and its count
        for word in set(words)),        # Set of unique words (remove duplicates)
    key=lambda p: p[1],                 # Order by the frequency of each word
    reverse=True)):                     # Descending order - less frequent words last

    # Do stuff with each sorted pair
```

What I'm doing here is just to take the input list `words`, get rid of the duplicates, then sort the words in descending order based on their frequency in the input text.

If I were to write this in C# using PLINQ, I'd do something like this:

```
var query = words.AsParallel().Distinct()
            .OrderByDescending(w => words.Count(s => s.Equals(w)))
            .Select((w, i) => (w, i));
```

I couldn't find an easy way to rewrite the paralell implementation in Python using possibly built-in libraries. I saw some guides about the [Pool](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) extension, but that looks like it's just an equivalent of the parallel `Select` operation, so I'd still miss how to implement the `Distinct` and `OrderByDescending` operations in Python, in parallel.

Is it possible to do this with built-in libraries, or are there commonly used 3rd party libraries to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your current approach is mostly based on `words.count(word)` inside a `for` loop. This means that you iterate the entire list for every unique word in `set(words)`, and only count a single word... instead, you can use [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and make a single pass of your list. The Counter object is a dictionary, which you can use for your key in sorting, with frequency lookups of O(1). Even for 1000 "words" in my example, the speed-up is dramatic... for longer inputs, I got bored waiting for `timeit` to finish :)

```
import string
from collections import Counter
import numpy as np # Just to create fake data

# Create some fake data
letters = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
new_words = [''.join(list(np.random.choice(letters, 3, replace=True))) 
             for x in range(1000)]


def original(search_list):
    """ Your current approach """
    for i, pair in enumerate(sorted(
    ((word, search_list.count(word)) 
        for word in set(search_list)),
    key=lambda p: p[1],
    reverse=True)):    
        pass


def new_approach(search_list):
    freq = Counter(search_list)
    search_list = sorted(search_list, key=lambda x: freq[x], reverse=True)
    new_list = []
    checked = set()
    for item in search_list:
        if item not in checked:
            new_list.append(item)
            checked.add(item)
```

For a list of 1000 "words":

```
%timeit original(new_words)
26.6 ms ± 289 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)


%timeit new_approach(new_words)
833 µs ± 30 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

You should see whether this new approach is suitable for your needs before trying to use something like `multiprocessing` as that may be adding extra code complexity that isn't necessary once you fix your time complexity issue.

EDIT:

As pointed out by the OP, we can skip the intermediate list and set by simply sorting the Counter object:

```
def new_approach(search_list):
    freq = Counter(search_list)
    search_list = enumerate(sorted(freq, key=lambda x: freq[x], reverse=True))
```

New timing:

```
%timeit new_approach(new_words)
438 µs ± 6.31 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: Thanks, the `Counter` class is perfect to solve this issue! I don't understand the code you posted though, I mean, why do you call `sorted` on the original `search_list`, which contains duplicates? Wouldn't it be better to just call `sorted` on the `freq` object (since a dictionary can be iterated), and then just `enumerate` on that sorted list? After all, I just need to iterate those unique words in descending order, I'm not sure why you're creating those two additional `new_list` and `checked` variables.

Comment: @Sergio0694 good question! First see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479928/why-is-the-order-in-dictionaries-and-sets-arbitrary/15479974)... I then looked into implementations of ordered sets and it adds a _lot_ of complexity I didn't think was necessary. The latest versions of Python are preserving order as an implementation point, not something to rely on on... that's changing in releases around now (3.6/3.7)

Comment: I wasn't talking about the sort order of the dictionary (as dictionaries, by definition, don't have a specific keys order), what I mean is: why don't you just call `enumerate(sorted(freq, key=lambda x: freq[x], reverse=True))` instead of iterating the original list, and then creating those two additional lists/sets later on? The sorted list returned by `sorted` should already be what I was looking for (regardless of the specific order of the dictionary, which depends on the specific implementation, as you said), right?

Comment: @Sergio0694 I think you might well be correct on that, I can't test in 2.7 right now. Until I can be sure of that, I'd still have to generate a list of keys from the dictionary and then sort that, so I'm not sure you gain much. I'm reluctant to update answer till I can test.

Comment: @Sergio0694 I can't see how it would differ in P 2.7 actually, so I will update the answer with timings. Thanks for pointing it out.